# What counts as participating in closure/deletion for Abominable?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I'm a lowly <3K user and I want the [Abominable](//winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/abominable) hat. Some questions:

- Can I earn this with a close *flag* rather than a VtC?
- Can I earn this by deleting my own question?
- Are there any other ways for a lowly <3K user like me to "participate" in a successful closure without posting intentionally bad questions?

Comment: I flagged for closure, then the question got closed and I got the hat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only votes that count are close votes and delete votes. Other flags do not count, I'm afraid.

Comment: So how you explain the hat given to users who only flagged? (see two answers on this question.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard how do *you* explain that users did flag and did not get the hat?

Comment: hmm....... Bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard try again

Comment: Gimme da codez and I shall tell. ;)

Comment: @sha teh codez do what we said above :)

Comment: So those who got the hat with less than 3k rep cast close/delete votes on their own posts?

Comment: Am I cleared to downvote the other answers to oblivion? ;)

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't correct. I got the hat on Hardware Recommendations by flagging a [question](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/relationship-between-ibm-lenovo) for closure.

Comment: @Glorfindel not exacly: flagging is not enough right now.

Comment: Ah, *right now*, so it has been changed.

Comment: @Glorfindel negative, it hasn't changed yet. However the trigger is a bit complex, I'm seeing if we can simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

You can earn it with a close flag. I too have less than 3k and I have earned the hat.

Comment: I flagged [this](//stackoverflow.com/questions/41214576/looking-for-a-free-or-low-cost-cloud-server-to-deploy-angular-2-node-js-web-app) and it was closed. I didn't get the hat.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely earn Abominable by voting or flagging a question for closure. I have Abominable on SO from a close flag, and on PPCG from a close vote. As for the others, I don't know for sure. It shouldn't be too hard to get - watch the new questions on SO and flag the unclear/duplicate ones.

Comment: …but I *have* raised a close flag though. I didn't get the hat.

Comment: @StephenLeppik You have to wait for the question to actually get closed (and for the system to award you the hat, which can take several minutes).