# Not receiving the Abominable hat?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2016

According to every single answer to [this question](/q/288390/335772), the Abominable hat can be earned by raising a close flag on a question that is later closed.

Let me be clear that I did this with [three](//stackoverflow.com/q/41214576/6388243) [separate](//stackoverflow.com/q/41233751/6388243) [questions](/q/210998/335772) and I did not receive the hat.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

---

Update: And, of course, after I'm told that I can't get the hat by flagging for closure, I get it by flagging for closure. Am I supposed to [flag a lot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNYDs.jpg) or something?

Comment: How long did you wait? #hatlag

Comment: @Panda Oh, wait, just noticed that the last one was hammered back open after a minute. Still the other two though.

Comment: @Panda hours...

Comment: Try closing more in the review queue

Comment: @Panda I don't have 3K. The linked question is *specifically about* <3K users.

Comment: Which is deleted... The hat should come soon due to #hatlag or #caching

Comment: @PythonMaster IT WAS CLOSED A DAY AGO. If I was going to get the hat from it then I would have gotten it by now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to our logs, you did not participate to the closure or deletion of any of those questions.

Unlike [incorrectly reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288390/what-counts-as-participating-in-closure-deletion-for-abominable), flagging does not cut it.